# Dynamic filled star in flutter

Tags: flutter

Am trying to create a star rating component which can dynamically fill from left.
So far I am able to create a crude star by using custom painter.

```
class StarPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double w = size.width;
    double h = size.height;

    Path path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, (2 * h) / 5)
      ..lineTo(w, (2 * h) / 5)
      ..lineTo(w / 5, h)
      ..lineTo(w / 2, 0)
      ..lineTo((4 * w) / 5, h)
      ..lineTo(0, (2 * h) / 5)
      ..close();

    Paint fillPaint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..color = Colors.black;

    // canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, fillPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

But I am not able to figure out how to show a portion of it as filled. As of now I have used a double stack one with +2 size which acts as the border and used a shader mask with linear gradient to show progress.

But can this be done without the crude way of stacking ?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: starSize,
            width: starSize,
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
                DynamicStar(percent: 1.0),
                Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: starSize - 2,
                    height: starSize - 2,
                    child: DynamicStar(percent: 0.8),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

class DynamicStar extends StatelessWidget {
  final double percent;
  const DynamicStar({Key? key, required this.percent}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      blendMode: BlendMode.srcATop,
      shaderCallback: (bounds) {
        return LinearGradient(
          tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
          colors: [Colors.black, Colors.white],
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
          stops: [percent, percent],
        ).createShader(bounds);
      },
      child: CustomPaint(painter: StarPainter()),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

EDIT: am trying to learn in flutter, so any clues on how to fix my code or snippets would help me better.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class SingleRatingIcon extends StatelessWidget {
      final IconData icon;
      final double size;
      final Color iconColor;
      final double rating;
    
      const SingleRatingIcon({super.key, required this.icon, required this.size, required this.iconColor, required this.rating});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ShaderMask(
          blendMode: BlendMode.srcATop,
          shaderCallback: (Rect rect) {
            return LinearGradient(
              stops: [0, rating / 10, rating / 10],
              colors: [iconColor, iconColor, iconColor.withOpacity(0)],
            ).createShader(rect);
          },
          child: SizedBox(
            width: size,
            height: size,
            child: Icon(icon, size: size, color: Colors.grey[300]),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**USAGE:**

```
      Row(
        children: [
          SingleRatingIcon(icon: Icons.star, size: 20, iconColor: Colors.yellow.shade800, rating: movieEntity.voteAverage),
          Text(movieEntity.voteAverage.toString(), style: textTheme.bodyMedium?.copyWith(color: Colors.yellow.shade800)),
        ],
      )
```

**VISUAL RESULT:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to below link

https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_star_rating

Or

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rating_bar

```
Smooth star rating example

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smooth_star_rating/smooth_star_rating.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var rating = 1.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Star rating',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: SmoothStarRating(
          rating: rating,
          isReadOnly: false,
          size: 80,
          filledIconData: Icons.star,
          halfFilledIconData: Icons.star_half,
          defaultIconData: Icons.star_border,
          starCount: 5,
          allowHalfRating: true,
          spacing: 2.0,
          onRated: (value) {
            print("rating value -> $value");
           
          },
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I did refer that, it uses `Icons.star` and that won't work for dynamic values right ? as its constrained by image. it can only show full, half or empty.

Comment: you can assign the dynamic value to rating and number of stars to starCount property in SmoothStarRating

Comment: Yes but it would only show half a star right ? can it show a star at 1/4 or any other fraction other than 1/2 ?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rating_bar. For ratings like 1/4th or 3.6 you can try this package.

Comment: None of those packages is what he asked for. He wants to fill ONE STAR, dynamically from left to right. Not many stars.